# how to load cocoa dylib from my application and call the method of dylib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dylib

I did not find any tutorials on creating and loading dylibs at runtime.just from the apple I have seen that `dlopen` will openthe `dylibs`.

I have created a cocoa dynamic library and added on method saying `-(void)displayMethod`.

I was in confusion like whether I need to copy only the `.dylib` file to my new project or entire folder of the dylib.

can any body give me good tutorial link which has info on How to set the path and how to load the cocoa dylibs.Currently I am using XCode4.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801709/xcode-4-adding-dylib)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to create your dynamic library as a dylib and not as a framework? The latter can be easily loaded at runtime using NSBundle (Apple provides an example snippet at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/principalClass ).